# Add custom page

Tags: 7

We can add a custom block with php code easily. Just enable php code and add a block. But what about a page? How can I add a page with custom php code?

Answer (score 11):

Since you already know how to provide a block through a custom module here is what you need to add:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function modulename_menu() {

  $items['your/special/path'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'title' => t('Title'),
    'description' => 'My custom and very special page',
    'page callback' => 'modulename_special_page',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Page callback.
 */
function modulename_special_page() {
  $content = 'Hello World';
  // ... do something and add to $content;
  return $content;
}
```

So first you need to register a path by implementing [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and there you need to provide a page callback which itself returns the contents of your page.

Check out the [example modules](https://drupal.org/project/examples) for further variations. There is one submodule that shows a lot of examples regarding registering new pages/tabs/etc.