# Custom page with fixed content

Tags: 7

Me again with the noob question.
I want to achieve this:
At the url `http://ROOT/something/{numeric_id_here}` to get a page that lists the header and the footer of the theme and my custom content. The content is not manage-able through the admin. It depends on the numeric id.
Here is what I got so far.
I use the `hook_menu` for this:

```
function something_menu() {
    $items['something/%id_here'] = array(
        'title' => 'Some title',
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );
    return $items;
}
```

I have the function that parses the url and gets the numerical value:

```
function id_here_load($arg) {
    $data = get my custom data from an external xml feed based on $arg; //this works nicelly - I get an array with the data I need.
    //WHAT'S NEXT?
}
```

Now I'm stuck. how can I pass `$data` to a template and render that template in the content of the page?
My question is somehow similar to [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/81539/39606). Just that the answers provided there don't cut it for me.

Comment: check out the hook_menu() docs https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7

Comment: @AndrewWelch I've been on that page at least 5 times. Looks like half Chinese to me. I forgot to mention that my drupal experience barely adds up to 2 man-days of work. Any suggestions or pieces of code I could try?

Comment: if you want to do an ajax call in your callback check out  something like this https://www.drupal.org/node/2046693

Comment: I don't need an ajax call. I need to list in the page `http://ROOT/something/{numeric_id_here}` the header and footer of my theme and the center part must come from a certain template.

Comment: why don't you  just use views then? https://www.drupal.org/project/views it allows you to set the template and I'm sure you could rewrite the url or just use the node id

Comment: I have a good reason why I don't use it. I have no idea what it does. :). And I was hoping for a simple out of the box way of doing it. I want to involve as few third party code as possible. But I will take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Views is the out of the box way of doing it. You could always hire a web developer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19011/discussion-between-andrew-welch-and-marius).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. Do your hook menu with (optional) arguments. In the callback do an entityFieldQuery (or pull in your XML). Use hook_theme to specify a custom template. this code isn't tested and will need some editing / adapting for your use context.

If you prefer to pull in a feed maybe https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds is what you are looking for.

//menu

```
/**
     * Implements hook_menu().
     */
    function example_menu() {
      $items = array();
      $items['example_object/something/%'] = array(
        'title' => t('callback'),
        'page callback' => '_example_mystuff',
        'page arguments' => array(
          0,
          1,
          2
        ),
        'access arguments' => array(
          ''
        ),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
      );
      return $items;
    }
```

//callback

```
     function _example_mystuff($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
        $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
//or load in your xml
        //do an entity field query to look up your items
         $results = $query->execute();
        return $results;
        }
```

//theme function

```
 function example_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
      return array(
    '_example_mystuff' => array(
          'template' => 'example-theme',
          'path' => $path . '/templates',
          'variables' => array(
            'variables' => NULL
          )
        )
    }
```

Comment: That's more like it. Explained for 5 year olds. Works perfectly. I needed to adjust some parameters but exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

You need more in your [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) like this:

```
function something_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['something/%id_here'] = array(
    'title' => 'Some title',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    // This is the function that will return your page content.
    'page callback' => 'something_custom_page',
    // This will pass the $data variable you returned from your loader function
    // into your page callback (not the ID in the URL).
    'page arguments' => array(1),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Then your load function needs to actually return what it has loaded, like this:

```
function id_here_load($arg) {
  // Do some checks o make sure no one can pass in bad data via the url.
  // This is an example you need to check based on your data.
  if (is_numeric($arg)) {
    $data = get my custom data from an external xml feed based on $arg; //this works nicelly - I get an array with the data I need.
    // If you get back valid data.
    // Again you need to make this relevant to your data.
    if ($data) {
      // Return the data.
      return $data;
    }
  }
  // If for any reason you didn't end up getting data return FALSE.
  // This will cause access denied for this page because of an invalid ID or something.
  return FALSE;
}
```

Then you need to implement your page callback function like this:

```
function something_custom_page($data = array()) {
  // Do something with the $data to create the page and return
  // either a string of HTML or a drupal render array.
  // Returning a render array is the preferred option.
}
```

See [Render Arrays in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/930760) form more info on render arrays.

Comment: Thanks. This works. But since it's kind of the same thing that Andrew answered and he answered first, I accepted his answer. Anyway +1 from me.